# Adding active/current class to get_terms list

Tags: loop, archives, terms

I have a list of terms I'm displaying using "get_terms". Each term is linked so if the user clicks it, they go to the term archive page.

```
 <?php $terms = get_terms('category');t
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach ($terms as $term) {
 echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';
 ?>
```

However, I would like to know if there's a way to add an "active" class to each term link if user goes to the term archive page.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 7):

Run a conditional check in the `foreach` loop using `is_category($term-name)`

Assign a class variable to `active` if it's the same as `$term->name`

```
$terms = get_terms( 'category' );
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $class = ( is_category( $term->name ) ) ? 'active' : ''; // assign this class if we're on the same category page as $term->name
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" class="' . $class . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

This version uses `is_tax` function that checks specifically for taxonomies.

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
  'taxonomy' => 'video-category',
  'hide_empty' => false
) );

if (!empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error($terms)){
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $class = ( is_tax('video-category', $term->slug) ) ? 'cat-item current-cat' : 'cat-item';
    echo '<li class="'.$class.'"><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) .'">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was the following solution that helped me. I hope I helped

```
$curTerm = $wp_query->queried_object;
$terms   = get_terms( 'product-category' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $classes = array();
        if ( $term->name == $curTerm->name ) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }
        echo '<li class="' . implode( ' ', $classes ) . '"><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

refer to [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671598/current-taxonomy-item-in-custom-taxonomy-term-page) for more details